# Highchart update BBox location on zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have created the BBox on a Average line. i have created the BBox by the following code

```
$('#container').highcharts({
               chart: {
                       zoomType: 'x',
                      }, 
                .
                .
                .
                .
            }, function(chart){
                if(chart.series[0].data[1])
                {
                    var point = chart.series[0].data[1],
                        text = chart.renderer.text(
                            'Average='+Math.ceil(point.y)+" s",
                            point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - 45,
                            point.plotY + chart.plotTop - 13
                        ).attr({
                            zIndex: 5
                        }).add(),
                        box = text.getBBox();
                    chart.renderer.rect(box.x - 5, box.y - 5, box.width + 10, box.height + 10, 5)
                        .attr({
                            fill: '#FFFFEF',
                            stroke: 'gray',
                            'stroke-width': 1,
                            zIndex: 4
                        })
                        .add();
                }

            });
```

the box have been created 
I want to change the BBox location according to average line when the zoom property in role. 
How can i do this ..Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your code in the [redraw()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.redraw) event in highcahrts. Take care about `destroy` (old rendered object) and create new one, or translate it.

Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/be2ebcg2/1/